# for loop in java for(feature city : cities)

Tags: java

I am working on a project which will read data into a list. I have a question in the for loop. How does the Feature city : cities work? I understand that cities is the list, but what does city means? city is not predefined, how does java understand city?

```
List<Feature> cities = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, cityFile);
    cityMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    for(Feature city : cities) {
      cityMarkers.add(new CityMarker(city));
    }
```

Comment: you're just iterating over your List. the Iterator just treats anything not equal to null in a container as an Object.

Comment: [enhanced-`for` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: 'city' is just the variable that you defined of type 'Feature' to be used as the iterator through the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a for each loop.what it does is this:
For each city in you city list it show perform what ever that is within the cury brace.the city is each city as you iterate over your city list

Comment: So it doesnt matter what I put over there? I can put for (Feature abc : cities)... ?

Comment: yes.it does not mater

Answer (score 0):

The compiler translates this into something that makes more sense. It probably comes out to something like:

```
ListIterator<Feature> cityIterator = cities.listIterator();
while(cityIterator.hasNext()) {
 cityMarkers.add(new CityMarker(cityIterator.next());
}
```

The enhanced for loop syntax using `:` just makes it easier to write and read the above code.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop your are doing a iteration on cities. 
city is a element of your list citie. 
In each iteration, the current element of the list is city.